# How to upload a digit with 000 in Google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have this code:

```
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var units1 = userProperties.getProperty('name');
 
  if (units1 = null){
    var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    userProperties.setProperty('name', '000');
  }
 
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  userProperties.setProperty('name', units1 + 1);
 
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var units = userProperties.getProperty('name');
```

The problem is that it does not add 000 - 0.01 - 0.02. It only adds 000 - 0.1 - 0.2.

Comment: Maybe because it sould be if( units1 == null )? Note units1 = null makes units1 null and if( un it1 = null ) is false

Comment: @Agoodperson, so, upon running it again and again, you want the units to be from `000`, to `0.01`, to `0.02`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your script into this one:

#### Script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  // since getProperty always returns string, parse it into float
  // if not instantiated, assign '000'
  var units1 = parseFloat(userProperties.getProperty('name')) || '000';
  Logger.log(units1)
  // add parseFloat in case units1 is still '000'
  userProperties.setProperty('name', parseFloat(units1) + 0.01)
  var units = userProperties.getProperty('name');
  Logger.log(units)
}
```

#### 1st run:

[image: 1st]

#### 2nd run:

[image: 2nd]

This should increment every run by `0.01`.